# map list of integers to dict keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary

The larger problem at view: I am breaking down a circle in 20 sectors to find where coordinates fall to find their value for a darts board game. There are 20 values 1-20 NOT in order. The dart board values fall along a circle:

[image]

I currently have a list of thetas (ranges of degrees) [(0-18),(18-36),(36-54)...]

I am trying to map the list of thetas to each sector of the dart board which corresponds to a different value, NOT in order.

The list of dart board values is such:

```
darts_list = [20,1,18,4,13,6,10,15,2,17,3,19,7,16,8,11,14,9,12,5]
```

Any idea how to get:

```
{20: (0-18), 1: (18-36), 18: (36-54)...}
```

So I can map the ranges of the theta to the dict values. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I think there was some confusion on what I was looking for, I didnt want 0 as dict values, so I changed to what I am looking for.

Python version: '3.4.5 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:47:47) \n[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]'

I believe the most efficient solution is to map the ranges to dart board values as keys. @jpp I am open to a more efficient solution instead of creating an XY problem.

Comment: You can use OrderedDict to do that

Comment: Why have the values be keys? Shouldn't the sectors be keys, so you can access the value for a sector more easily?

Comment: I don't understand why you need your dictionary to be ordered. How are your theta ranges stored? Can you post your list of theta ranges, if you have this available?

Comment: What python version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Given it's not clear why you require an `OrderedDict`, I present a solution which efficiently maps your dart board to angle ranges.

```
darts_list = [20,1,18,4,13,6,10,15,2,17,3,19,7,16,8,11,14,9,12,5]
theta_ranges = ((n*18, (n+1)*18) for n in range(20))

d = dict(zip(darts_list, theta_ranges))

# {20: (0, 18), 1: (18, 36), 18: (36, 54), 4: (54, 72),
#  13: (72, 90), 6: (90, 108), 10: (108, 126),
#  15: (126, 144), 2: (144, 162), 17: (162, 180),
#  3: (180, 198), 19: (198, 216), 7: (216, 234),
#  16: (234, 252), 8: (252, 270), 11: (270, 288),
#  14: (288, 306), 9: (306, 324), 12: (324, 342), 5: (342, 360)}
```

If you need to map ranges via a dictionary, also consider subclassing `dict` and mapping ranges to values as so:

```
class dict_range(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, value):
        key = next((k for k in self.keys() if k[0] <= value < k[1]), None)
        return self.get(key) if key else None

d = dict_range(dict(zip(theta_ranges, darts_list)))

d[15]   # 20, i.e. 15 degrees value = 20
d[275]  # 11, i.e. 275 degrees value = 11
d[375]  # None
```

Answer (score 1):

Before Python 3.6 `dict` was unordered. As of Python 3.7 `dict` being ordered is a language feature.

Unordered means that the things stored in `dict` are not guaranteed to be stored in the same order as they were added. So the usual solution is to use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

darts_list = [20,1,18,4,13,6,10,15,2,17,3,19,7,16,8,11,14,9,12,5]

od = OrderedDict((x, 0) for x in darts_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

***Edited question:***

> Any idea how to get:

```
{20: (0-18), 1: (18-36), 18: (36-54)...}
```

Answer:

Create a new dictionary with `dict()` and zip your keys and values:

```
>>> dict(zip(darts_list, theta_ranges)))
{20: (0, 18), 1: (18, 36), 18: (36, 54), 4: (54, 72), ...
```

This works also with `OrderedDict` if you use Python <= 3.6 and want an order:

```
>>> OrderedDict(zip(darts_list, theta_ranges))
OrderedDict([(20, (0, 18)),
             (1, (18, 36)),
             (18, (36, 54)),
             (4, (54, 72)), ...
```

***Old question:***

> Any idea how to get:

```
{20: 0, 1: 0, 18: 0...}
```

Answer:

Because the value for all keys is `0`, you can use the `fromkeys()` method:

> Returns a new dict with keys from iterable and values equal to value.

Python >= 3.6 (ordered dicts)

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(darts_list, 0)
{20: 0, 1: 0, 18: 0, 4: 0, 13: 0, 6: 0, 10: 0, 15: 0, 2: 0, 17: 0, 3: 0, 19: 0, 7: 0, 16: 0, 8: 0, 11: 0, 14: 0, 9: 0, 12: 0, 5: 0}
```

Python < 3.6

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict.fromkeys(darts_list, 0)
OrderedDict([(20, 0), (1, 0), (18, 0), (4, 0), (13, 0), (6, 0), (10, 0), (15, 0), (2, 0), (17, 0), (3, 0), (19, 0), (7, 0), (16, 0), (8, 0), (11, 0), (14, 0), (9, 0), (12, 0), (5, 0)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple dictionary comprehension.

Only in python 3.6.  As @Alex pointed out,  use OrdereDict if using python below 3.6.

```
 darts = {k: 0 for k in darts_list}

 {20: 0, 1: 0, 18: 0, 4: 0, 13: 0, 6: 0, 10: 0, 15: 0, 2: 0, 17: 0, 3: 0, 19: 0, 7: 0, 16: 0, 8: 0, 11: 0, 14: 0, 9: 0, 12: 0, 5: 0}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
darts_list = [20,1,18,4,13,6,10,15,2,17,3,19,7,16,8,11,14,9,12,5]
d=dict()
for c in darts_list:
    d[c]=0
```